# Select query ignoring objects whose id attribute is inside an int array?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have a List containing several objects, I want to add to a new List onjects that satisfy certain conditions, also I have an int array containing `id key` of some objects.

```
int[] selectedIDs = new int[] { 10, 22, 31, 42, 5 };
```

How can I select from a list of several objects, those that are not on that int array and also other condition is state is off.

- State off is done, but I do not know how to add the part of ignoring those ids within int array
- Each object has an attribute `idObj`, like `obj.idObj`

to select all objects I am doing

```
List<myObj> objs = allObjectsList.Where(s => s.SelectedByDisplay == objectState.OFF).ToList();
```

How to ignore objects whose id is inside int array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add another condition in your `Where` clause:

```
!selectedIDs.Contains(s.idObj)
```

So your statement would be:

```
List<myObj> objs = allObjectsList
                         .Where(s => s.SelectedByDisplay == objectState.OFF
                                    && !selectedIDs.Contains(s.idObj))
                          .ToList();
```